# linux traffic routing through vpn instead of proxy on eth0

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, proxy, debian-wheezy

okay im running kali linux on a network with a proxy but blocks certain sites like youtube and imdb etc, recently i got a vpn which allowed me to access this site so i would use one browser(firefox) for my proxy and another browser (chrome) for the vpn. This was working perfectly until suddenly all my connections started being routed through the vpn instead of my lan... as soon as i connect to the vpn firefox would give a message saying it cant find the proxy and even applications like apt-get would also not route traffic through the proxy. So what id want is for all the traffic to route through the proxy unless i set it to go through the vpn

Comment: Wrong default route? Check your routing table.

Comment: @scai yah ive researched it and when i inpute the route command i see the deafault gateway is the vpn one...if i change it connections through the vpn dont work anymore

Comment: i connect to the internet via lan cable to proxy (192.168.5.249) and the vpn is vpnbook.com.firefox browser uses the proxy and chrome the vpn but now when i connect to the vpn firefox and any other program are having trouble connecting to the proxy but connections to the vpn work just fine...id like certain connections to go through the proxy which is faster and the restricted ones to go through the vpn

Comment: Check your routing rules. If you just want to route a few sites through the VPN then set set up a single route for each site and let your default route go to your regular non-VPN gateway.

Comment: @scai that is a university proxy the number of blocked sites like youtube hulu are numerous im just wondering what went wrong...it was working perfectly until suddenly everything started going through the vpn...i actually thought it was some network stuff i was playing with so i formatted my machine and now after formatting connections are still going through the vpn instead of the proxy

Comment: We just know way to less about your current setup to be able to help you.

Comment: okay what information can i provide?

Comment: @scai network settings are automatically given by a dhcp server but one needs to put the proxy address of the university which is 192.168.5.249...it however blocks access to various sites so thats why i use a public vpn from vpnbook.com.

Comment: Your routing rules and an exact explanation of what should be routed where according to your plan.

Comment: @scai im trying to put the output for my route command but its not formatting right